# php dynamically generate file with argument

Tags: php

I'm new to web programing and just started using php. I wonder if there's a way to dynamic generate a file (like html) by passing an argument. like by calling some function

```
some_function($my_arr)
```

and

```
$my_arr={$obj1, $obj2, $obj3}
```

while obj is just a class with some class member in it.
Is it possible to dynamically generate 3 file (such as html) that prints the info of three objects to some format seperately in each of them?

Comment: This is usually called a `template`. It is very well possible to do this, so I advise you to search for PHP template engine. You'll find some, undoubtedly.

Comment: @GolezTrol i wrote my own template and it worked. thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script would be useful to you if this file generation is only for once and when you are not checking whether the file has already been generated earlier.

```
//let generate_files be our function with $array which is an array as the parameter
// this script generates txt files with names as array element values

function generate_files ( $array )
    {
       foreach ( $array as $value )
          { 
            $handle = fopen($value.'txt', 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$value);
            $data = 'This is the data inside each file';
            fwrite($handle, $data);
          }  
    }
```

If this files are generated temporarily then you can delete all these files after operation by using unlink($my_file); fumction.